# AngularJS 2.0 http.post returns 500 (Internal server error)

Tags: laravel, angular

I'm trying to use angular 2.0 to add a new hero via my PHP Laravel API and I always get 500 Internal server error response.

**My API (laravel)**: Create a new hero route:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => ['web']), function()
    {   
     //Add a new hero
    Route::post('/heroes/create', 'HeroController@store');
    });
```

HeroController@store method: (Tested and works with a Laravel form)

```
/**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $hero = new Hero;
        $hero->name = $request->name;
        $hero->description = $request->description;
        $hero->avatar = "None";
        $hero->save();

        $heroes = Hero::paginate(5);
        return view('/heroes/index', [
        'heroes' => $heroes
    ]);
    }
```

**Angular onSubmit() Method: (trying to make it work without a form..)**

```
onSubmit(value: string): void {  
      let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    let formPayload = new URLSearchParams();
    formPayload.set('name', name.value);
    formPayload.set('description', desc.value);
    formPayload.set('_token', _token.value);

    this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1/heroWorld/public/api/v1/heroes/create', 
                       JSON.stringify({name:'Joe',description:'wonder', _token:'knUS8vUxihTj4YJhjVkqmRBJJkVDDCABIZaRwXhN'}),
                       {headers:headers})
.map((res: Response) => res.json())
.subscribe(
        data => { this.heroes = data;
        },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('done');
      );
```

What I get:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1/heroWorld/public/api/v1/heroes/create 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

What's wrong? I'm trying to fix it for several days, nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

You create a form data using the `URLSearchParams` class but you use another object in the `post` method. You could try the following instead:

```
let formPayload = new URLSearchParams();
formPayload.set('name', name.value);
formPayload.set('description', desc.value);
formPayload.set('_token', _token.value);

this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1/heroWorld/public/api/v1/heroes/create', 
                   formPayload.toString(), // <------
                   {headers:headers})
```

Comment: I made it only for testing purposes, in both cases I get 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Do you have the corresponding error on the server side?

Comment: I have laravel "Add Hero form" which sends the data to my store() method, and it works (as I mentioned in my post). Seem like i'm missing someting with the anulgar app..